# Android Intent causes NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: android, android-intent, noclassdeffounderror

I have encountered the NoClassDefFoundError when trying to create a new Intent to start a Service. I have checked several suggested solutions such as including libraries in the /libs path, I believe that I have these set up correctly. I have included my manifest and source below. Any help would be really appreciated.

Here is a screen capture of my file structure inside Eclipse
[image]

Here is my Manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.ajinex.easysave"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >
    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="11" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE"></uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"></uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"></uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"></uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"></uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"></uses-permission>
<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".CouponsActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:launchMode="singleInstance"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_coupons" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
        <!--  service  -->
        <service android:enabled="true" android:name=".LocationCheckService" >
    </service>
</application>
```

Here is my calling code from the MainActivity:

```
Intent LocationCheck = new Intent(this, LocationCheckService.class);
    this.startService(LocationCheck);
```

Here is my LocationCheckService.class

```
public class LocationCheckService extends Service {
    public class LocalBinder extends Binder {
        LocationCheckService getService() {
            return LocationCheckService.this;
        }
    }


    public final IBinder mBinder = new LocalBinder();

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return mBinder;
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        if(checkNetworkRechability()){
            Toast.makeText(this, "EasySave Service Started", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            getSysLocation();
        }
        return START_STICKY;
    }
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {

    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {

    }
}
```

Here is some LogCat output relating to the issue:

```
07-16 00:09:36.712: I/AndroidRuntime(312): NOTE: attach of thread 'Binder Thread #3' failed
07-16 00:09:37.702: W/ActivityManager(59): Unable to start service Intent { act=com.ajinex.easysave.location.LocationCheckService }: not found
07-16 00:09:38.162: I/ActivityManager(59): Displayed activity   com.ajinex.easysave/.MainActivity: 1568 ms (total 1568 ms)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the error message (com.ajinex.easysave.location.LocationCheckService) and the package name (com.ajinex.easysave) you need to declare the service as .location.LocationCheckService in the manifest file.

Comment: When I set the service name as .location.LocationCheckService I receive a classNotFoundException but the package still compiles

Comment: Hi Yuri, thank you for your assistance, on this occasion Imran's solution (above) has solved my issue. Thank you so much for your input!

Comment: Please note that I changed the manifest to .location.LocationCheckService, it was part of the solution. Doing so caused the classNotFoundException but when I implemented Imran's proposed solution combined with yours the issue was resolved!

Comment: No problem Mat.  But I still don't understand how Imran's solution works if the package name 'com.ajinex.easysave.LocationCheckService' is obviously incorrect.

Comment: @Yuri : can you explain it if package name `com.ajinex.easysave` then how my solution is incorrect

Comment: Hi Imran, I'm not saying it is incorrect. I'm just saying that the class name, based on the error message, is com.ajinex.easysave.location.LocationCheckService, not com.ajinex.easysave.LocationCheckService.  This I believe was the root cause of the problem.

Comment: Yuri, as I wrote in the earlier note, I implemented your suggestion of the correct package name, this was part of the fix, the second part was implementing Imran's suggestion.

Comment: Mat, I believe your original code was correct.  All you had to do is to modify the service name in the manifest and probably clean up your project because latest ADT tools sometimes do not pick up the changes.  P.S. This is my last comment :)

Comment: @Yuri, You were quite correct also, after cleaning the project everything worked as expected! Cheers mate!

Answer (score 1):

try as:

```
    Intent LocationCheck = new Intent();
    LocationCheck.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.ajinex.easysave", 
    "com.ajinex.easysave.LocationCheckService"));
    this.startService(LocationCheck);
```